# JSON Table View Swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift, parsing, tableview

I've managed to call a JSON URL with the code below. How would I extract a property from the output? I have Date, Event, Hasta, and Location properties.

**Here is JSON Structure & XCode output:**

https://www.kimonolabs.com/apis/7flcy3qm#data

**Here is my swift code**

```
class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 52.0/255.0, green: 170.0/255.0, blue: 220.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]

        let url = NSURL(string:"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/7flcy3qm?apikey=gNq3hB1j0NtBdAvXJLEFx8JaqtDG8y6Y")!
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let urlContent = data {

                do {

               let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

                    print(jsonResult)

                } catch {

                    print("JSON Serialization Failed") 
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

How would I extract the properties? Thanks a lot

Comment: Can't see the linked "whatever" without signing up. BTW, love all the blank lines. ;-)

Comment: `jsonResult` is either a dictionary or an array. You need to cast it (like `if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? [String : AnyObject]` for example) and then you can access its members like `jsonResult["someKey"]` within the scope of that conditional cast

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I'll see if I have any luck!

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to go about that haha! Can someone write a firm example for me, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a good site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial) that explains how to parse JSON. Basically, you're checking on each `if let` statement if the thing you're checking for exists in the JSON, so your app won't crash if the thing you're looking for doesn't exist in the JSON.

This way, you can safely put JSON into a Swift Dictionary and use it in your table view.

Another good tutorial on JSON with Swift:
[iOS Creator JSON with Swift](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/json-parsing-tutorial-ios8-swift)

Or you can try this custom library for Swift with JSON (which is a little easier):
[SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)